# Creating a responsivness layout for a website

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I want to create a website with flutter. Unforunatly I have some problems with coding the layout.

I want to have a responsivness layout, so I tried to find the most common resolutions for mobile, tablet and laptop. This resolutions should help me to decide when the screensize is small, medium or large.

I recently started this project, so I am still a beginner and hope that you guys can help me to figure out, how to solve this error messages.

At the moment I have the problem, that I get this error messages from the code below:

```
   lib/helpers/responsiveness.dart:16:14: Error: The parameter 'largeScreen' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type 'Widget', but the implicit default value is 'null'.
 - 'Widget' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.
        this.largeScreen,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/helpers/responsiveness.dart:17:14: Error: The parameter 'mediumScreen' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type 'Widget', but the implicit default value is 'null'.
 - 'Widget' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.
        this.mediumScreen,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/helpers/responsiveness.dart:18:14: Error: The parameter 'smallScreen' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type 'Widget', but the implicit default value is 'null'.
 - 'Widget' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.
        this.smallScreen,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/helpers/responsiveness.dart:47:18: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'Widget' which excludes null.
 - 'Widget' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
          return mediumScreen ?? largeScreen;  //if medium screen is null then return large screen
                 ^
lib/helpers/responsiveness.dart:50:16: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'Widget' which excludes null.
 - 'Widget' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
        return smallScreen ?? largeScreen;    //if small screen is null then return large screen
               ^
Failed to compile application.
```

here my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const int largeScreenSize = 1366;     //laptop resolution
const int mediumScreenSize = 768;     //Tablet resolution
const int smallScreenSize = 360;      //mobile resolution
const int customScreenSize = 1100;    //most common custom resolution

class ResponsiveWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget largeScreen;
  final Widget mediumScreen;
  final Widget smallScreen;
  //final Widget customScreen;

  const ResponsiveWidget(
      {Key? key, @required
        this.largeScreen,
        this.mediumScreen,
        this.smallScreen,
        //this.customScreen
      })
      : super(key: key);

static bool isSmallScreen (BuildContext context) =>       //smaller than smallScreenSize = small screen
    MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < smallScreenSize;

static bool isMediumScreen (BuildContext context) =>      //larger or equal than mediumScreenSize but  smaller than largeScreenSize = medium screen
    MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >= mediumScreenSize &&
    MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < largeScreenSize;

static bool isLargeScreen (BuildContext context) =>      //larger or equal than largeScreen = large screen
    MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >= largeScreenSize;

static bool isCustomScreen (BuildContext context) =>    //everything between medium and custom screen size is custom screen size
    MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >= mediumScreenSize &&
    MediaQuery.of(context).size.width <= customScreenSize;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints){
      double _width = constraints.maxWidth;
      if (_width >= largeScreenSize) {
        return largeScreen;
      }
      else
        if (_width < largeScreenSize && _width >= mediumScreenSize){
          return mediumScreen ?? largeScreen;  //if medium screen is null then return large screen
        }
        else {
        return smallScreen ?? largeScreen;    //if small screen is null then return large screen
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your constructors you must provide all three different screen sizes

```
 final Widget largeScreen;
  final Widget mediumScreen;
  final Widget smallScreen;
```

Without the nullable operator `?` means you must provide a value

> Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.
> this.largeScreen,

in this case you can solve this by making your widgets nullable

```
 final Widget? largeScreen;
  final Widget? mediumScreen;
  final Widget? smallScreen;
```

also here is a better responsive widget using `LayoutBuilder`

```
// ignore_for_file: type_annotate_public_apis, sort_constructors_first

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ResponsiveWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget? largeScreen;
  final Widget? mediumScreen;
  final Widget? smallScreen;
  const ResponsiveWidget({
    Key? key,
    this.largeScreen,
    this.mediumScreen,
    this.smallScreen,
  }) : super(key: key);
  static bool isSmallScreen(BuildContext context) {
    return MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 800;
  }

  static bool isLargeScreen(BuildContext context) {
    return MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 800;
  }

  static bool isMediumScreen(BuildContext context) {
    return MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >= 800 &&
        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width <= 1200;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
        if (constraints.maxWidth > 1200) {
          return Container(child: largeScreen ??smallScreen);
        } else if (constraints.maxWidth <= 1200 &&
            constraints.maxWidth >= 800) {
          return Container(child: mediumScreen??smallScreen);
        } else {
          return smallScreen!;
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Responsive Layout in Flutter you can use flutter_bootstrap package. This package is too good and easy to use. Check this page [flutter_bootstrap](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bootstrap)